# For the given data find the clusters. Assume the relevant parameters needed

Tags: clustering, dataset, data-mining

[image: DATA TABLE]

Below is the given data, how can I make clusters using symmetric matrix?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.